# Copy all jars from subprojects to root project’s bin directory

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'd like to copy every jar generated from subprojects from their `/bin/libs` dir to the root project's `bin` dir. Unfortunately, my current code just copies **everything** from the subprojects into that directory:

```
task muleapp(type: Copy) {
    from '.'
    include '**/bin/libs/*.jar'
    into 'bin'
}
```

How can I achieve the desired functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this type of task:

```
task muleapp(type: Copy) {
    def jars=[]
    subprojects.each {
        jars+=it.libsDir
    }
    from jars
    into 'bin'
}
```